# How to draw polygon on Google Maps using API v3 with SQL Server and Visual Studio 2008 C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, google-maps-api-3

I had uploaded my shapefile to SQL Server by using Shape2SQL and now I have this table with a column named "geom" and the data is in this format:

`POLYGON(Longitude,Latitude)`

Now I do not know where to start. I want to use the data in "geom" to draw polygons on Google Maps using C# and Google Maps API v3. I had googled about this but still unable to get a clear idea on how to do it.

Can you guys please help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript.

This shouldn't be too hard to learn with a few examples as Google has this well documented. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon)Is the section on overlaying polygons.

Full reference guide is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference).

There are some third party API wrappers, like [Google Maps API for .NET](http://gmaps.codeplex.com/), but these are unlikely to be as full featured. Using Javascript is going to be the easiest way to accomplish what you are after, even if you already know some C#.

Comment: is it I need to export my data from sql server to a xml file then only use javascript to show my polygon on google map?